# Getting mask values in numpy data

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy masked array:

```
masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 ..., 
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 ..., 
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]],
       fill_value = 65536.0)
```

When I do this:

```
numpy.unique(arr.data)
```

I get:

```
array([  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+00,
         3.00000000e+00,   4.00000000e+00,   5.00000000e+00,
         6.55360000e+04])
```

How do I NOT get the masked values in the arr.data?

Comment: Given that `arr.data` returns the original (non-masked) data, that implies one of your original values is 65536, which is confusing.

Comment: But you can find the answer in [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#accessing-the-data).

Comment: thanks @Evert, the link helps. If one of the original values is 65536.0, there must be an error somewhere in my code before. if you want to write an answer, i will be happy to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I do this:
>
> ```
> numpy.unique(arr.data)
> ```
>
> How do I NOT get the masked values in the arr.data?

`arr.data` has nothing to do with masked values--rather it's a regular old numpy.array:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

my_data = np.array([10])
print(repr(my_data))

x = ma.array(
    data = my_data,
    mask = [True],
    fill_value = 65536.0
)
print(repr(x))
print(repr(x.data))

--output:--
array([10])

masked_array(data = [--],
             mask = [ True],
       fill_value = 65536)

array([10])
```

And, when you call `unique()` on an array, you get the unique elements as a 1D array:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

data = np.array([
    [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
    [4.0, 5.0, 65536.0],
])

print(np.unique(data))

--output:--

[  1.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+00   4.00000000e+00
   5.00000000e+00   6.55360000e+04]
```

Here's your masked array:

```
data = np.array([
    [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
    [4.0, 5.0, 65536.0],
])

mask = [
    [True, True, True],
    [True, True, True],
]

x = ma.array(
    data=data,
    mask=mask,
    fill_value = 65536.0
)

print(repr(x))
```

---

```
masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- --]
 [-- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]],
       fill_value = 65536.0)
```

---

```
print(
   np.unique(x.data)
)
```

---

```
[  1.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+00   4.00000000e+00
   5.00000000e+00   6.55360000e+04]
```